# AVR C - .init8 routine ignored by compiler

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, avr

I wanted to add my custom routine to the init sequence, however the compiler seems to dislike it and it's not included in the generated hex.

```
// 8th init vector, naked
void init_io() __attribute__((naked)) __attribute__((section(".init8")));

void init_io() {
    DDRB    = OUT_PINS;
    PORTB   = IN_PINS; // pullup on input
}

void main() {
    // stuff
}
```

It's almost exactly copied from the manual, but it doesn't work.

Here's a piece of the asm listing where I expected my routine to end:

```
  10:   07 c0           rjmp    .+14        ; 0x20 <__bad_interrupt>
  12:   06 c0           rjmp    .+12        ; 0x20 <__bad_interrupt>

00000014 <__ctors_end>:
  14:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  16:   1f be           out 0x3f, r1    ; 63
  18:   cf e9           ldi r28, 0x9F   ; 159
  1a:   cd bf           out 0x3d, r28   ; 61
  1c:   02 d0           rcall   .+4         ; 0x22 <main>
  1e:   0c c0           rjmp    .+24        ; 0x38 <_exit>

// HERE IT SHOULD BE SOMEWHERE

00000020 <__bad_interrupt>:
  20:   ef cf           rjmp    .-34        ; 0x0 <__vectors>

00000022 <main>:
```

Comment: Okay, turns out it's just optimized away. How do I force it to be kept?

Comment: Compare it to the entry in the manual that it's "almost" a copy of.

Comment: Only difference is that they use `(void)` instead of `()`.

Comment: Why should I? That's just a minor syntax difference, I'm compiling with C99 so it's not needed.

Comment: "Why should I?" -- Because theirs works and yours doesn't? "That's just a minor syntax difference" -- it's the difference between having a prototype or not. "I'm compiling with C99" -- irrelevant.